# Razor Page - 400 error when using the "action" tag to redirect to url when clicking on a button wrapped in a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a property `Url` in my page Model that I have set up as a `[BindProperty]`. This property contains the url I want to redirect to when a user clicks on the `Back` Button. However when I click on the back button I get a 400 error even though I can see the url string has been correctly added to the url.

If I then simply refresh the page, the page I want to redirect to loads as expected.

Why am I getting a 400 error? and how can I stop it from happening?

**cshtml page:**

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model AppName.AppVariablesModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AppVariables";
}
<br />
<h2 style="text-align:center">App Variables</h2>
<br/>
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; cursor:default; width:50%;" class="table-bordered center">
    @foreach (var dict in Model.AppVariablesDict)
    {
        <tr style="cursor:default;">
            <th style="color:white;">@dict.Key</th>
            <td style="color:black;">@dict.Value</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br/>
<form action="@Model.Url" method="POST">
    <body style="text-align:center">
        <button type="submit" style="color:black;" class="btn-sm ml-auto mr-1" title="Back">
            Back
        </button>
    </body>
</form>
```

**cshtml.cs page:**

```
namespace AppName
{
    public class AppVariablesModel : PageModel
    {
       [BindProperty]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

public void OnGet(int id, string db, string server, string url)
        {
           Url = url;
        }
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what `@Model.Url` is?

Comment: Couldn't you use `<a href="@Model.Url">Back</a>` if you want to redirect url? `type="submit"` will go to the `onPost` handler to submit the form.What do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is using the http POST verb but you are trying to command using the GET verb. It can't route on a form post in this manner. You are mismatched.

Key things to look at:

form action="@Model.Url" method="**POST**"

public void **OnGet**

Either change your form method to use Get instead or implement a OnPost() method instead of the OnGet

Answer (score 4):

Besides,Razor Pages are automatically protected from XSRF/CSRF, if you want to do `POST` method, you also need to supply AntiForgeryToken,refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1

So, the solution is that you need to both implement an `OnPost` handler for url and add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form.

CalculationVariablesModel.cshtml

```
<form action="@Model.Url" method="Post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
</form>
```

PageModel:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    //...
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: .Net core automatically injects the antiforgery token by default via the FormTagHelper so you do not have to do this. You alternatively have to manually opt out of the generation. The methodology you are showing above is akin to full framework MVC sites but if you are going that route then you also have to decorate your post verb with the [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken] attribute.